# haskell packages: base versus haskel98

Tags: haskell

I installed haskell-platform on my Ubuntu system. Now I need to run

```
ghci -package haskell98 -hide-package base
```

in order to try out simple things like:

```
 map Char.toUpper "Hello World"
```

Is there a way to make this the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can just put those options in your `~/.ghci` file:

```
:set -hide-package base
:set -package haskell98
```

But, I really recommend you **don't** do this. Just get used to the modern libraries.

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> map Data.Char.toUpper "Hello"
"HELLO"
```

Or

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> toUpper <$> "Hello"
"HELLO"
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not even sure GHC 8 still comes with the Haskell98 library.  Something about it being incompatible with the GHC changes for the AMP update.

Comment: Interesting... although that seems weird, since the AMP is already in 7.10. Also, you can _always_ `RebindableSyntax` to anything else. But, I suppose just nobody really cares that much for keeping haskell98.

Comment: Ah, ok, `haskell98` actually requires `base<4.8`, i.e. it doesn't work already with GHC-7.10. Still a bit strange IMO...